# Applescript Adobe Updater

Tags: applescript, auto-updates

So, I am new to Applescript editor and I am trying to write code to automatically update computers.
For some odd reason I can not seem to get Adobe to update successfully.
I tried using Accessibility Inspector, but nothing appeared like AXButton
So is there even a way of writing code for Adobe when there is not an AXButton option?

This is the code:

```
tell application "Adobe Application Manager"
    activate
end tell
delay 7.0
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Adobe Application Manager"
        click button "Update" of window "Adobe Application Manager"
    end tell
end tell
```

and this is the error message:

error "System Events got an error: Can’t get button \"Update\" of window \"Adobe Application Manager\" of process \"Adobe Application Manager\"." number -1728 from button "Update" of window "Adobe Application Manager" of process "Adobe Application Manager

Comment: This is programming question, so it should belong to [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/applescript) or [AD](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applescript), therefore it should be closed in here. Very similar [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5612277/55075).

Comment: As a workaround, use System Events to tab to the target button and press the space bar to actuate the button.